# Spacemacs : insert single character in normal mode

Tags: spacemacs, insert, vim-emulation

I am using Spacemacs in Vim mode, and I would like to be able to insert a single character while remaining in normal mode, as described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_a_single_character) for Vim.
For example, typing `SPC i k` in normal mode would insert k where the cursor stands, while `SPC a k` would insert k on the right of the cursor; exactly the same as pressing `i k <ESC>` and `a k <ESC> l` (the `l` aiming at putting the cursor back where it was) respectively.

P.S.: Making the command repeatable through `.` and allowing for multiple repetitions as in `5 i k` would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's an Evil-specific way to do this. However, you can write a short Elisp snippet that does this:

```
(defun my/insert-char (char count)
  (interactive "c\np")
  (insert-char char count))
```

When you map `insert-char` to a key directly, it will prompt you for the character, which is why I wrapped it in `my/insert-char`.

The function can be bound to `SPC i i` (as `SPC i` is used for 'insertion' by Spacemacs) as follows:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys (kbd "ii") 'my/insert-char)
```

Now you can do `10 SPC i i k` to insert 10 `k`'s, and repeat the previous command 10 times using `10 .`

**Update:**
The following function implements the append-behavior, which needs some extra treatment to prevent inserting letters into the next line, and to keep the point in the same location:

```
(defun my/append-char (char count)
  (interactive "c\np")
  (save-excursion
    (unless (eolp)
      (forward-char))
    (insert-char char count)))
```